# trying to get my public and private key from seed Phrase on solana

Tags: javascript, wallet, solana-web3js

I'm trying to get my public and private key from my seed Phrase on solana but they are different and I don't understand why and can't find a solution and I really need your help please. here's my code:

```
import { Keypair } from '@solana/web3.js';

const SEED_STRING = "I paste my seed Phrase here";

const seed = Uint8Array.from(SEED_STRING.split(",")).slice(0, 32);

const keypair = Keypair.fromSeed(seed);

console.log("Private Key:", keypair.privateKey);
console.log("Public Key:", keypair.publicKey);
```

this is the error that I get: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvmOH.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, **error messages**, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557